# Docker copy file - no such file or directory

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I cannot copy file to container from my host.

this is my docker file :

```
COPY /vagrant/somefile.json  somefile.json
```

This is the full path to the file :

```
/vagrant/somefile.json
```

this is the path of the Dockerfile:

```
/vagrant/static/app/Dockerfile
```

i get :

```
 ---> dba663c523a9
Step 3/20 : COPY /vagrant/somefile.json  somefile.json
ERROR: Service 'node' failed to build: COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder330278780/vagrant/somfile.json: no such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0):

To quote the [`COPY` documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy):

> The  path must be inside the context of the build

In layman's words, any file you want to copy in to the container needs to be in the same directory as the `Dockerfile`, or some subdirectory of it. If you start by placing `somefile.json` in `/vagrant/static/app/`, you should be able to use:

```
COPY ./somefile.json somefile.json
```

Answer (score 0):

Generic Format:

> copy_command     source_file    Destination

Please try this!

```
COPY /vagrant/somefile.json  /root/somefile.json
```

OR

```
COPY /vagrant/somefile.json  /tmp/somefile.json
```

OR

```
mkdir ~/new
COPY /vagrant/somefile.json  ~/new/somefile.json
```